# Can I use reflection on Prism's EventAggregator?

Tags: c#, reflection, prism, eventaggregator

I am trying to refactor some of my methods in the PRISM framework, and it's not really working out.

I need to publish messages through the `EventAggregator`, and I have written a reflection method which will look through a `List<Parameters>` containing `Type`s and from here send the messages.
But it never sends any messages.

It turns out the safecast `as PubSubEvent<object>` is not the same as `public class Input: PubSubEvent<Output> {}`, which means the `returnObj?.Publish(data);` is `null` and will not be called.

```
public struct Parameters
{
    public string Topic;
    public Type Input;
    public Type Output;
}


private List<Parameters> _list;
...
void SomeFunction()
{
    _list.ForEach(m =>
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataString, m.Output);

        var eventAggType = _eventAggregator.GetType();
        var eventMethod = eventAggType.GetMethod("GetEvent");
        var genericMethod = eventMethod.MakeGenericMethod(m.Input);
        var returnObj = genericMethod.Invoke(_eventAggregator, null) as PubSubEvent<object>;
        returnObj?.Publish(data);

        // var datType = returnObj.GetType();
        // if (datType.BaseType.Name == typeof (PubSubEvent<object>).Name)
        // {
        //  var obj = Convert.ChangeType(returnObj, datType);
        //  ((PubSubEvent<object>) obj).Publish(data);
        // }
    }
}
```

I tried to modify the code by looking at the type it actually outputs (remove the `as PubSubEvent<object>`), and it's the same `BaseType`.
But the casting to a basic `PubSubEvent` is not something the program is happy about.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in MyProject.ModuleA.dll

EXCEPTION: Unable to cast object of type 'MyProject.ModuleA.GlobalEvents.EventA' to type 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents.PubSubEvent`1[System.Object]'.
```

How do I `Publish` with the correct type?
It should look like the following, if you knew what classes you were handling:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<EventA>().Publish(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. It's reflection - with more reflection!

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    _list.ForEach(m =>
    {
        //Deserialize the data
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataString, m.Output);

        //Obtain the object from the EventAggregator
        var eventAggType = _eventAggregator.GetType();
        var eventMethod = eventAggType.GetMethod("GetEvent");
        var genericMethod = eventMethod.MakeGenericMethod(m.Input);
        var returnObj = genericMethod.Invoke(_eventAggregator, null);

        //Publish the data
        var publishMethod = returnObj.GetType().GetMethod("Publish");
        publishMethod.Invoke(returnObj, new[] {data});
    });
}
```

So you take the reflection, `returnObj`, and reflect the function `Publish(...)` and `Invoke` it from your reflected object, `returnObj`, with the `data` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

What about passing the generic type to the `void SomeFunction()`

```
void SomeFunction<T>()
{
    // ..............

    var returnObj = genericMethod.Invoke(_eventAggregator, null) as PubSubEvent<T>;
    returnObj?.Publish(data);
}


// call it like:
SomeFunction<DataObject>();
```

---

**Update:**

Calling a generic method from a Type, can be done like this:

```
void SomeFunction<T>()
{
    // ..............

    var returnObj = genericMethod.Invoke(_eventAggregator, null) as PubSubEvent<T>;
    returnObj?.Publish(data);
}


// call it like:

// this is the type you want to pass.
Type genericType = typeof(int);

// get the MethodInfo
var someFunctionMethodInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("SomeFunction", BindingFlags.Public);

// create a generic from it
var genericSomeFunctionMethodInfo = someFunctionMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericType);

// invoke it.
genericSomeFunctionMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

Comment: Yes, I should elaborate.

When I attempt to call `SomeFunction()` I am passing a stored `Type` from a `List<Parameters>`.
So I run the `_list.foreach( m=> ...` where I only know the type from this list.

Perhaps the `List<>` can be rewritten to something else to make it fit?

Comment: You should bring the foreach outside the function. Then it is possible to call the method with a specific type. See my update above. _(like the trick you did above with generics)_

Comment: Yes, not bad - So I can do more reflection outside the genereic method, or I can do another two lines of reflection inside the function (I found a solution).